# Screen rotation on a per view basis

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7

With iOS7, even though the app has the Device Orientation under General set to landscape and portrait. There are some screens in my app that I do NOT want to be able to rotate.

How can you pick and choose which views get rotated when the device turns?

I tried to use shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation but I could not get it to work.

Anyone accomplished this with the new software?

Answer (score 1):

try the following code in the views that you want it to be just landscape and change the landscape part to portrait in the views that you want it to be only portrait.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: No luck, it seems a lot of people on SO are having  the same issue. Have tried a few solutions with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` and return `NO`.